# get element after page loads

Tags: javascript, function, call

how do i call a function to count the number of divs with an id of 'd1' after the page loads. right now i have it in my  section but doesnt that execute the script before anything in the  loads? because it works if i put the code below the div tags...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly there should be at most one because IDs aren't meant to be repeated.

Second, in straight Javascript you can call [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById) to verify it exists or [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to loop through all the divs and count the number that match your criteria.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("d1");
if (elem) {
  // it exists
}
```

or

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { 
  var div = divs[i];
  if (div.id == "d1") {
    count++;
  }
}
```

But I can't guarantee the correct behaviour of this because like I said, IDs are meant to be unique and when they're not behaviour is undefined.

Comment: ok i have 8 divs, they are positioned absolute, they are inside a parent div, i want the bottom of the child div, to be at the top of the parent div. if that makes sense, so basicly there are 2 divs, the child div on top of the parent div. do you know how i can loop through them to do this? also the child div is dynamic so i cant really do it in css

Comment: I don't really understand the request but the answer is probably to learn/use jquery :)

Comment: @David: i don't really understand either but it almost sounds like a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery's document.ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()) or hook up to the onLoad event.

Answer (score 0):

well an ID should be unique so the answer should be one.

you can use `<body onload='myFunc()'>` to call a script once the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the function tied to the `onload` event, like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var divElements = document.getElementById("d1");
    var divCount = divElements.length;
    alert(divCount);
};
```

For the record, you should only have one div with that ID, as having more than one is invalid and may cause problems.